# Unwrapping Swift optional without variable reassignment

Tags: swift, option-type

When using optional binding to unwrap a single method call (or optional chaining for a long method call chain), the syntax is clear and understandable:

```
if let childTitle = theItem.getChildItem()?.getTitle() {
    ...
}
```

But, when provided the variable as a parameter, I find myself either using:

```
func someFunction(childTitle: String?) {
    if let theChildTitle = childTitle {
        ...
    }
}
```

or even just redefining it with the same name:

`if let childTitle = childTitle { ... }`

And I've started wondering if there is a shortcut or more efficient of performing a `nil` check for the sole purpose of using an existing variable. I've imagined something like:

`if let childTitle { ... }`

Does something like this exist, or at least an alternative to my above two interim solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit/update: **Xcode 14 • Swift 5.7**

[swift-evolution proposal SE-0345 if let shorthand for shadowing an existing optional variable](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0345-if-let-shorthand.md):

```
if let childTitle {

}
```

---

```
guard let childTitle else {
    return
}
```

---

Original answer

No. You should unwrap your optionals just redefining it with the same name as you mentioned. This way you don't need to create a second var.

```
func someFunction(childTitle: String?) {
    if let childTitle = childTitle {
        ...
    }
}
```

update: **Xcode 7.1.1 • Swift 2.1**

You can also use guard as follow:

```
func someFunction(childTitle: String?) {
    guard let childTitle = childTitle else {
        return
    }

    // childTitle it is not nil after the guard statement
    print(childTitle)
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, and mention it in my question - however, I'm wondering if there is `"... at least an alternative to my above two interim solutions?"`

Comment: @craig sorry did not notice that BTW thats the recommended approach. forget about the other ones

Comment: I don't see any other solution. You could just use your parameter as an optional but if the code you're going to write requires a non-nilable value, you must use optional binding.
Hopefully, Apple will improve this situation in Swift 1.2+

Comment: Interesting that you can reuse the same name. Apparently this is called [variable shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250151).

Comment: I wish Swift had a special keyword to make that last code block less ugly, like... guard unwrap childTitle else{

Comment: @TealShift check my last edit

Comment: @JamesToomey check my last edit

Comment: @LeoDabus Love that they added this syntax!

Comment: @JamesToomey me too. Looks much better

Comment: @JamesToomey Swift 5.8 has already implemented [SE-0365](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0365-implicit-self-weak-capture.md) as well which is really welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here's the only alternative I'm aware of.

```
func someFunction(childTitle: String?) {
    if childTitle != nil {
        ...
    }
}
```

But then `childTitle` is still an optional, so you would have to unwrap it every time you use it: `childTitle!.doSomething()`. It shouldn't affect performance, though.

Answer (score -1):

I've gotten into the habit of just reassigning to the same name. That eliminates the need to come up with a separate name and avoids any confusion about whether the new name is supposed to be used anywhere. However, note the output after the block:

```
var test: String? = "123"
if var test = test {
    test += "4"
    test += "5"
}
print(test) // prints "123"
```

If you need to access the modified value after the block, you can assign the variable to a new name and assign the new name back to the old name inside the block:

```
var test: String? = "123"
if var testWorking = test {
    testWorking += "4"
    testWorking += "5"
    test = testWorking
}
print(test) // prints "12345"
```